# Grabbing Top 5 Events From Multiple Columns in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

My file has four sets of columns I want to grab the top 5 out of. There are four columns with names and four columns with total dollar amount in them. I assume the issue I am having it the MATCH() formula grabs the row number, however each row could have up to four dollars and names in it. Thus creating an `#N/A` error when I try it. The formula I am trying is:

```
=INDEX(Franchise,MATCH(I37,Totals,0))
```

The `Franchise` being the four columns of names and the `Totals` being the four columns of totals.

At this point I am stumped.

How would I go about creating that formula?

You can see where I want the formula and results to post at the top.

Here is [the file](http://mtbzu.com/Tracker.xlsx).

Comment: Question: Would the top 2 be "Alfonso 6, $520,152" and "Bill 5, $251642"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the top 5 Totals and use those to retrieve the Q*x* (or other) label. The [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) does not like discontiguous cell ranges but the newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) has a LARGE subfunction (**14**) and you can force it to ignore errors with option **6**. Forcing anything that isn't in column D, H, L or P into a `#DIV/0!` error will discard them from any calculation.

In M2 use this standard formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, $D$10:$P$35/NOT(MOD(COLUMN($D:$P), 4)), ROW(1:1))
```

In K2 use this standard formula to retrieve the Q*x* label:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$10:$C$35, MATCH(M2, $D$10:$D$35, 0)),
 IFERROR(INDEX($G$10:$G$35, MATCH(M2, $H$10:$H$35, 0)),
 IFERROR(INDEX($K$10:$K$35, MATCH(M2, $L$10:$L$35, 0)),
         INDEX($O$10:$O$35, MATCH(M2, $P$10:$P$35, 0)))))
```

Fill K2:M2 down to K6:M6. Your results should resemble the following.

[image: AGGREGATE LARGE with error]

> Caveat - If there are ties in the top 5 amounts, a more complicated formula would have to be devised to account for multiple events with identical totals.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: That worked awesome! I don't think I would have figured this out by myself. I need to learn more for sure.

Also, I am not worried about duplicates. I can change one amount by a dollar.

Comment: Nice technique Jeeped. I learnt something there about the discontiguous ranges and using the NOT division...